# Sort array of objects by containing string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I am trying to sort an array of objects by substring/string

```
var substring = 'nord';
var arrayOfObjs = [0: {label: "Nordals", value: "s29"}
1: {label: "Skåstrup Strand", value: "s12"}
2: {label: "Blokhus", value: "s61"}
3: {label: "Fanø", value: "s27"}
4: {label: "Rømø", value: "s26"}
5: {label: "Vorupør", value: "s66"}
6: {label: "Grønhøj", value: "s41"}
7: {label: "Nr. Lyngby ved Løkken", value: "s14"}
8: {label: "Nordjylland", value: "6"}
9: {label: "Nordsjælland", value: "7"}
10: {label: "Vestjylland", value: "10"}
11: {label: "Tyskland", value: "13"}];
```

**I have this function to sort:**

```
function compare(a, b) {
  // Use toUpperCase() to ignore character casing
  const areaA = a.label.toUpperCase();
  const areaB = b.label.toUpperCase();

  let comparison = 0;
  if (areaA > areaB) {
    comparison = 1;
  } else if (areaA < areaB) {
    comparison = -1;
  }
  return comparison;
}
```

**Before sorting:**

```
0: {label: "Nordals", value: "s29"}
1: {label: "Skåstrup Strand", value: "s12"}
2: {label: "Blokhus", value: "s61"}
3: {label: "Fanø", value: "s27"}
4: {label: "Rømø", value: "s26"}
5: {label: "Vorupør", value: "s66"}
6: {label: "Grønhøj", value: "s41"}
7: {label: "Nr. Lyngby ved Løkken", value: "s14"}
8: {label: "Nordjylland", value: "6"}
9: {label: "Nordsjælland", value: "7"}
10: {label: "Vestjylland", value: "10"}
11: {label: "Tyskland", value: "13"}
```

**After sorting:**

```
0: {label: "Blokhus", value: "s61"}
1: {label: "Fanø", value: "s27"}
2: {label: "Grønhøj", value: "s41"}
3: {label: "Nordals", value: "s29"}
4: {label: "Nordjylland", value: "6"}
5: {label: "Nordsjælland", value: "7"}
6: {label: "Nr. Lyngby ved Løkken", value: "s14"}
7: {label: "Rømø", value: "s26"}
8: {label: "Skåstrup Strand", value: "s12"}
9: {label: "Tyskland", value: "13"}
10: {label: "Vestjylland", value: "10"}
11: {label: "Vorupør", value: "s66"}
```

The array of objects is being sorted by the alphabet, but I need to sort the `arrayOfObjects` by the substring, so basically every `arrayOfObjs[x].label` that is closest to the `substring` variable has to come first in the sorted results?

How would I add this functionality?

**It should look something like this because the 3 first contains the 'nord' string:**

```
0: {label: "Nordals", value: "s29"}
1: {label: "Nordjylland", value: "6"}
2: {label: "Nordsjælland", value: "7"}
3: {label: "Blokhus", value: "s61"}
4: {label: "Fanø", value: "s27"}
5: {label: "Grønhøj", value: "s41"}
6: {label: "Nr. Lyngby ved Løkken", value: "s14"}
7: {label: "Rømø", value: "s26"}
8: {label: "Skåstrup Strand", value: "s12"}
9: {label: "Tyskland", value: "13"}
10: {label: "Vestjylland", value: "10"}
11: {label: "Vorupør", value: "s66"}
```

I have tried browsing through stack overflow, but I was unable to find anything, if this is a duplicate please show me the path.

Comment: you can use any of the solution, I updated your code, hope it helps, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort by substring and then by alphabet.

```js
var array = [{ label: "Nordals", value: "s29" }, { label: "Skåstrup Strand", value: "s12" }, { label: "Blokhus", value: "s61" }, { label: "Fanø", value: "s27" }, { label: "Rømø", value: "s26" }, { label: "Vorupør", value: "s66" }, { label: "Grønhøj", value: "s41" }, { label: "Nr. Lyngby ved Løkken", value: "s14" }, { label: "Nordjylland", value: "6" }, { label: "Nordsjælland", value: "7" }, { label: "Vestjylland", value: "10" }, { label: "Tyskland", value: "13" }],
    string = 'nord';

array.sort((a, b) =>
    b.label.toLowerCase().includes(string) - a.label.toLowerCase().includes(string) ||
    a.label.localeCompare(b.label)
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

IE version with classic function and [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(string) === -1) - (b.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(string) === -1)
        || a.label.localeCompare(b.label);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, exactly what i were looking for

Comment: Is there a way to make this IE compatible, does not work with includes

Comment: you are nothing less than amazing, thank you so much :) !

Answer (score 0):

First you have to apply search on String then sorting i.e.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  // Use toUpperCase() to ignore character casing
  const areaA = a.label.toUpperCase();
  const areaB = b.label.toUpperCase();

  let comparison = 0;
  if(areaA .includes("substring")){ // check if sub-string available 
  if (areaA > areaB) {
    comparison = 1;
  } else if (areaA < areaB) {
    comparison = -1;
  }
}else{
  //based on where you put the unsorted object (1 or -1)
}
  return comparison;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  arrayOfObjs.sort((a, b) => (a.label.toLowerCase().match(/nord/) != null) ? -1 : (b.label.toLowerCase().match(/nord/) != null) ? 1 : (a.label > b.label) ? 1: -1);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-9m946j